# pst-marble package fails with lualatex

Tags: luatex, pstricks, luapstricks

It seems the [pst-marble](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-marble) package has issues when used with lualatex. The example `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-marble}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psMarble(8,8)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

compiles as expected with `xelatex` and `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` but hangs with `lualatex`, displaying in the terminal

```
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count288
\scratchdimen=\dimen180
\scratchbox=\box57
\nofMPsegments=\count289
\nofMParguments=\count290
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count291
\MPscratchDim=\dimen181
\MPnumerator=\count292
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count293
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
) [1
```

and then repeatedly printing the line

```
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
```

I don't think the above should cause an issue, but I'll note adding `\DocumentMetadata{}` to the top of the tex file does not stop it from hanging, it just stops printing this line.

Here is the log file after cutting off compilation.

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (MiKTeX 23.1) (format=lualatex 2023.3.19)  19 MAR 2023 08:38
 restricted system commands enabled.
**mydocument.tex
(./mydocument.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2022-10-03.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/f
ontloader-2022-10-03.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.120
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'. L3 programm
ing layer <2023-02-22>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'.
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pst-marble/pst-marble.s
ty
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
Package: pstricks 2022/19/23 v0.72 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 227.

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count191
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count192
\pstFP@xia=\count193
\pstFP@xib=\count194
\pstFP@xfa=\count195
\pstFP@xfb=\count196
\pstFP@rega=\count197
\pstFP@regb=\count198
\pstFP@regs=\count199
\pstFP@times=\count266
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.st
y
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.st
y
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil
-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks18
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen140
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen141
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil
-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.
code.tex
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.s
ty
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys
.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys
libraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
)))
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code
.tex
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.
code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen142
\pgf@xa=\dimen143
\pgf@xb=\dimen144
\pgf@xc=\dimen145
\pgf@y=\dimen146
\pgf@ya=\dimen147
\pgf@yb=\dimen148
\pgf@yc=\dimen149
\c@pgf@counta=\count267
\c@pgf@countb=\count268
\c@pgf@countc=\count269
\c@pgf@countd=\count270
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparse
r.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen150
\pgfmath@count=\count271
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.basic.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.random.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.base.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.round.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.misc.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunct
ions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.
code.tex)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat
.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count272
)))
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.
code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen151
\pgffor@skip=\dimen152
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
\psLoopIndex=\count273

`PSTricks' v3.18  <2022/11/28> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen153
\pst@dimb=\dimen154
\pst@dimc=\dimen155
\pst@dimd=\dimen156
\pst@dimg=\dimen157
\pst@dimh=\dimen158
\pst@dimm=\dimen159
\pst@dimn=\dimen160
\pst@dimo=\dimen161
\pst@dimp=\dimen162
\pst@hbox=\box53
\pst@ibox=\box54
\pst@boxg=\box55
\pst@cnta=\count274
\pst@cntb=\count275
\pst@cntc=\count276
\pst@cntd=\count277
\pst@cntg=\count278
\pst@cnth=\count279
\pst@cntm=\count280
\pst@cntn=\count281
\pst@cnto=\count282
\pst@cntp=\count283
\@zero=\count284
\pst@toks=\toks27
--- We are running lualatex with luapstricks ---
Lua module: luapstricks 2023-02-17 v0.8 PSTricks backend for LuaLaTeX
Lua function luaPST = 26
Lua function luaPSTcolor = 27
Lua function luaPSTbox = 28
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-col
or.tex)
\psunit=\dimen163
\psxunit=\dimen164
\psyunit=\dimen165
\pst@C@@rType=\count285
\pslinewidth=\dimen166
\psk@startLW=\dimen167
\psk@endLW=\dimen168

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-arr
ows.tex
\pshooklength=\dimen169
\pshookwidth=\dimen170
)
\pst@customdefs=\toks28

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-dot
s.tex)
\pslinearc=\dimen171
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen172
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen173
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen174
\everypsbox=\toks29
\psframesep=\dimen175
\pslabelsep=\dimen176
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen177
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen178
\pst@shift=\dimen179
\ps@imagectr=\count286
)
File: pstricks.tex 2022/11/28 v3.18 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
File: pst-fp.tex 2020/11/20 v0.06 `PST-fp' (hv)
)
Package: pst-marble 2019/02/18 package wrapper for PSTricks pst-marble.tex

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pst-marble/pst-marble
.tex `PST' v1.6, 2019/03/20)
File: pst-marble.tex 2019/03/20 v1.6 `PST-marble'
)
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-lua
tex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count287
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box56
)
No file mydocument.aux.

\openout1 = mydocument.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 4
.
(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2022/07/10 v2.5l Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

(C:/Users/saint/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count288
\scratchdimen=\dimen180
\scratchbox=\box57
\nofMPsegments=\count289
\nofMParguments=\count290
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count291
\MPscratchDim=\dimen181
\MPnumerator=\count292
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count293
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
) [1


Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is 
not loaded.
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: It does work, but it's very, very slow. Your document compiled on my system in roughly 2 minutes.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Apologies for my impatience! Is there something particular about the PS code in this package that makes it so slow with luapstricks? The code is quite involved, but why would it take so much longer than with xetex or latex+dvips?

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but I think it's nothing specific in the package. `luapstricks` emulates PostScript in Lua and adds quite a bit of overhead. For many usecases of pstricks this isn't that bad since there are no big computation involved, so even with the overhead it can still be very fast. But `pst-marble` is doing a lot of computations so it shows a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for `lualatex` which needs the `shell-escape` option when running:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pst-marble} 
\usepackage[pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dNOSAFER}]{auto-pst-pdf-lua} 
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{dejavu-otf} 
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
  \usepackage{dejavu}
\fi 
\begin{document}
foo

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psMarble(8,8)
\end{pspicture}

bar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @MarcelKrüger in the comments, the compilation does not hang, it just takes quite a long time (3 minutes on my machine, longer for more complicated examples like in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-marble/doc/pst-marble-doc.pdf)).

I mistakenly assumed that repeated printing of

```
Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is not loaded.
```

meant something was wrong, though I'm still not sure why it happens.

Comment: with `LuaLaTeX` you should always add `\DocumentMetadata{}`  as first line